(Tao) Lemma 3.4.9: Let $X$ be a set, then show the set $\{Y:Y\subseteq X\}$ is a set, from the powerset axiom.
Relevant definitions:
Definition 3.3.1 (Functions): Let $X,Y$ be sets, and let $P(x,y)$
be a property pertaining to an object $x\in X$ and an object $y\in Y$,such that for every $x\in X$, there is exactly one $y\in Y$ for which
$P(x,y)$ is true (this is sometimes known as the vertical line test). Then we define the function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ defined by $P$ on the
domain $X$ and range $Y$ to be the object which, given any input
$x\in X$, assigns an output $f(x)\in Y$, defined to be the unique
object $f(x)$ for which $P(x,f(x))$ is true. Thus, for any $x\in X$ and
$y\in Y$, $y = f(x)\Leftrightarrow P(x, y)$ is true.
Axiom 3.10 (Power set axiom): Let $X$ and $Y$ be sets. Then there
exists a set, denoted $Y^X$, which consists of all the functions from
$X$ to $Y$, thus...
$f\in Y^X$$\Leftrightarrow$ ($f$ is a function with domain $X$ and range $Y$).
Axiom 3.6 (Replacement). Let $A$ be a set. For any object $x\in
A$, and any object $y$, suppose we have a statement $P(x,y)$ pertaining to $x$ and $y$, such that for each $x\in
A$ there is at most one $y$ for which $P(x,y)$ is true. Then there exists a set $\{y:P(x,y)~\text{is true for some}~x\in A\}$, such that for any object $z$,
$z\in\{y:P(x,y)~\text{is true for some}~x\in A\}\Leftrightarrow P(x,z)~ \text{is true for some}~x\in A$

My Attempt: Consider the set $X^X$, then $f\in X^X$ is a necessary and sufficient condition for $f:X\rightarrow X$. Now consider the property $P(f,Y):\text{ran}(f)=Y$. By the Axiom of Replacement there exist a set $\{Y: (f:X\rightarrow X) \wedge (\text{ran}(f)=Y)\}$ or more succintly $\{Y:Y\subseteq X\}$. Q.E.D
Question: According to the Axiom of Replacement, the set $Y$ must be unique in the proof(It must correspond to exactly one $f$).Is it okay to define $ran(f)=Y$ or is this circular? Also,how do I show $Y$ is unique?

I find your definition of $P(f,Y)$ confusing - it should be a statement concerning $f$ and $Y$ (which assumes that these are already "chosen"), while your statement is quantifying over $f$ and $Y$, so it's just one single statement (with conflict of notation).

Does Tao actually write $f\in Y^X$ means $f$ has range $Y$?  (It seems unlikely to me)

@BrianMoehring Yes he does, I think it may follow from his definition of a function, which I've added to my question.

@MichałMiśkiewicz I suppose that is the essence of my question. I have made an edit to the post so that $P$ is more legible.

Do you think that your Y is unique? i.e. for any set y, there's exactly one function with that range?

@altwoa I see now that $Y$ as defined in $\text{ran}(f)=Y$ is in fact not unique. I think the best definition of $Y$ is such that $f$ is surjective.  Because If $f:X\to Y$ and $f:X\to Z$ are surjective then $Y=Z$. This extra condition will gaurentee the uniqueness of $Y$.

Unfortunately the word 'range' is ambiguous: does Tao mean 'image' or 'codomain'? (I believe at least neither of those is ambiguous!)

@JamesM I belive he most ceartinly means range as the codomain by his definition of a function.

Def.3.4.1 The image f(S) is a set. Thus, applying Replacement to the set $2^X$ we get all the subsets of X.

Let $X^X$ denote the set of all functions from $X$ to $X$. Let $Y$ be an arbitrary non-empty subset of $X$ and $f$ an element in $X^X$. Let $P(f,Y)$ be the property such that $f:X\to Y$ is surjective. It is not hard to see that there is at most one $Y$ such that this property holds. By replacement the set $$\{Y:f:X\to Y\text{where $f$ is surjective for some $f\in X^X$ and $Y\neq \emptyset $}\}$$ must exist. Additionally for any subset of $X$,$Z$, there must exist a $f\in X^X$ such that $f:X\to Z$ is surjective, simply by virtue of $f$ being well defined. If $Z$ is empty then every $f$ is surjective vacuously.Thus $Z\subseteq X$ iff there exist a $f\in X^X$ such that $f:X\to Z$ is surjective. So the set $$\{Y:f:X\to Y\text{where $f$ is surjective for some $f\in X^X$ and $Y\neq \emptyset $}\}$$ is equivalent to $\{Y:Y\subseteq X\ \text{and $Y\neq\emptyset$ }\}.$ Now we simply state $\{Y:Y\subseteq X\ \text{and $Y\neq\emptyset$ }\}\cup \{\emptyset \}$. Q.E.D
